# Is there a way to merge images in JavaScript without using canvas?

Tags: javascript, image-processing, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to export an image (PNG) which is larger than [the maximum canvas size](https://github.com/jhildenbiddle/canvas-size#test-results). I've tiled the canvas export, so that each tile is small enough to be generated (with [toBlob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob)). Now I need a way to merge the images together, but can't find a way that itself doesn't use a canvas. Is this possible somehow?

Comment: Yes, you can use a [PNG encoder (untested)](https://github.com/image-js/fast-png), build your own ImageData from your tiles and that should do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Kaiido](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3702797/kaiido)'s answer worked great. I'm tiling the canvas export with [getImageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData) (moving the contents of the canvas for each tile), then loop over all ImageData tiles & creating a new 1D array of RGBA values which I send to [fast-png](https://github.com/image-js/fast-png)'s `encode`. It's not very fast, especially on mobile (a ~30MP image takes about 40s to merge on an iPhone X), but I'm doing it on a background thread with a Worker.